# Airflow + DBT Configuration

Tags: git, airflow, dbt

I'm starting learn dbt and I'm long time Airflow user.
I've built, ran and tested a dbt model and I've pushed it to a remote repo. Now, I want pull this remote to another repo where is my Airflow DAGs. My Airflow structure is the following:

```
~/airflow
    - .git
    - dags/
```

But I have some questions:

1. I read the `git submodule` the best way to pull my dbt repo on my Airflow repo. Am I correct?
2. Which location should I have to pull my dbt repo?
3. If I built other dbt project, how shoud I have to config my dbt to support two projects?

I hope be clear, but let me know if you need any detail.
Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that

1. You have airflow jobs running already in a machine where you have DBT installed
2. You have your DBT project in another repo which you want to add to your Airflow repo inside DAGS folder so you trigger DBT jobs.

You can indeed do it using [subtree](https://gitcheatsheet.org/how-to/git-subtree-add).

Once you have this, if you have DBT installed Airflow can run DBT DAGS.